# Can not access fm radio in nokia s40 c3-00

Tags: nokia, series-40, fm-radio

I am trying to access the ondevice fm radio through JSR 234 in c3-00 . Everything seems to work fine but the radio can not be accessed. I have also checked supported JSRs for nokia c3 which is a s40 v6 device which shows that it supports JSR 234. I have used the following simple code to do this:

```
player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://radio");
player.realize();
// declared and configured a tuner object.
player.start();
```

I have also searched a lot but didn't found anything about it.